# Runtime Error 1004 On formula R1C1 vba

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have some trouble applying a FORMULAR1C1 to a range.
This is the code i been using:

```
Range("AE6:AE" & conter).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-28],'[" & namebook & "]" & namesheet & "'!C1:C4,4,FALSE)"
```

where Conter is the number of rows that will applying the formula, namebook is the name of the woorkbook (without path) and namesheet is the name of the sheet that are looking the info for the vlookup.
the reason that i used a variable is that the file update daily and change the name because the date.
When i run this i get the runtime error 1004 what can i solve this? thanks

Comment: Can you show us how you declared `conter`, `namebook`, and `namesheet`? (also, that's not a typo, right, "conter"?)

Comment: thank you for your answer BruceWayne i declared conter as long,namebook and namesheet as string.

Comment: How are they set though, IE `conter = 3` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's better of you stick with one style of `Range`.

You want to use `FormulaR1C1`, and your first `VLOOKUP` parameter is `RC[-28]`, but the second one you are using `C1:C4`.

Also, you have a few "extra" `'` that needs to be removed.

Modify your code to the line below:

```
Range("AE6:AE" & conter).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-28],[" & namebook & "]" & namesheet & "!R1C3:R4C3,4,FALSE)"
```

Comment: It confused me too, but C1:C4 is valid RC notation.

Comment: @SJR true, but still I think it's better to stick with one style, that was my recommendation . The error (from my tests) is in the extra `'` in his formula